# How to omit the last value of a liveData when the fragment / activity is recreated?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a problem with liveData in a particular case. When the response from a http service is Code = 2, it means that the session token has expired. In that case I navigate to the LoginFragment to login the user again. If the user logs in, then I return to the fragment which was previously and when I start to observe the liveData in **onViewCreated** function, it gives me its last value which is: Code = 2, so the Application navigates back to the login, which is wrong.

*I have a Sealed Class:*

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    var data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null,
    val Code: Int? = null

) {
    class Success<T>(data: T?) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String, code: Int? = null) : Resource<T>(message = message, Code = code)
    class Loading<T> : Resource<T>()
}
```

*This is the code on the ViewModel:*

```
val mLiveData: MutableLiveData<Resource<Data>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        mLiveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        try {
            if (app.hasInternetConnection()) {
                // get Data From API
                val response = repository.getData()
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    mLiveData.postValue(Resource.Success(parseSuccessResponse(response.body())))
                } else {
                    mLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(parseErrorResponse(response.body())))
                }
            } else {
                mLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error("Connection Fail"))
            }
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            when (t) {
                is IOException -> mLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error("Connection Fail"))
                else -> mLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error("Convertion Fail"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*This is the code on the fragment, **observeForData()** is called in **onViewCreated** function:*

```
private fun observeForData() {
    mLiveData.getData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        when (response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                isLoading = false
                updateUI(response.data)
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                isLoading = false
                if (response.Code == 2) {
                    // Token Expired
                    navigateToLogin()
                } else {
                    showErrorMessage(response.message)
                }
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                isLoading = true
            }
        }
    })
}
```

How can i solve this?
Is there a way to remove the last value or state from a liveData when the fragment is destroyed when navigating to the LoginFragment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change last updated value for live data,You can set "Resource" class with default null values when onDestroy().

```
onDestroy(){
//in java ,it will be new Resource instance
Resource resourceWithNull=new Resource();

mLiveData.setValue(resourceWithNull);
}
```

when you relaunch the fragment live data will emit Resource with null value as  response.

Then You can write your code with in observer

```
if(response.data!=null)
{
//your code

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One often-suggested solution is [SingleLiveEvent](https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70), which is a simple class you can copy-paste into your project.

For a framework solution, I suggest SharedFlow. Some Android developers recommend switching from LiveData to Flows anyway to better decouple data from views. If you give SharedFlow a replay value of 0, new Activities and Fragments that observe it will not get the previous value, only newly posted values.

Sample untested ViewModel code:

```
val dataFlow: Flow<Resource<Data>> = MutableSharedFlow(replay = 0)

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        // Same as your code, but replace mLiveData.postValue with dataFlow.emit
    }
}
```

And in the Fragment:

```
private fun observeForData() {
    isLoading = true
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        mLiveData.dataFlow
            .flowWithLifecycle(this, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
            .collect { onDataResourceUpdate(it) }
    }
}

// (Broken out into function to reduce nesting)
private fun onDataResourceUpdate(resource: Resource): Unit = when(resource) {
    is Resource.Success -> {
        isLoading = false
        updateUI(response.data)
    }
    is Resource.Error -> {
        isLoading = false
        if (response.Code == 2) {
            // Token Expired
            navigateToLogin()
        } else {
            showErrorMessage(response.message)
        }
    }
    is Resource.Loading -> isLoading = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will consider using SharedFlow for future projects. But androidLearner's answer is the one that best suits my project